How to pass the "xsl:initial-template" in Altova XMLSpy 2024
I want to process JSON by XSLT 3.0. I am using Altova XMLSpy 2024. I can't seem to find how to initiate the processing without at least one dummy XML file and a <xsl:template match="/">.

Where do I pass the name of my initial template in XMLSpy?

And how can I make a  <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template"> picked up by the processor inside XMLSpy without requiring a dummy XML input file?


@MartinHonnen was so kind as to provide an answer to an earlier question of mine which included a template <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template"> but I could not get it to work in XMLSpy without a dummy XML input file:
XSLT 3.0 Processing JSON: improving a functions-based solution
I would like to use that example.
I need to use XMLSpy so any suggestions for other processors are sadly of no use to me.
Thank you.
I have also searched the Altova online help but it was fruitless. Any link describing how to do it in XMLSpy is very much apprechiated.

Consider to ask Altova support whether and if so how it is possible to use an initial template with XSLT 3. I am not sure they provide such an option and I don't have access to the current version 2024.

Curious whether you got information from Altova support whether and if so how it is possible or whether they told you it is not possible.
